# Remove the Required field for the postcode at the checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, address, checkout-page, zipcode

Remove the required field for the postcode for the billing and shiping Address

Answer (score 1):

You can override checkout_index_index.xml file in your custom theme and remove required-entry validation at

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="string">true</item>
  </item>

</item>
```

Flush cache to reflect changes.